# stack build error: attribute ‘ghc822’ missing, at (string):1:53

Tags: haskell-stack, nixos

I am attempting to build my haskell project on NixOS.

Running `$ stack build` gives the following error.

```
$ stack build
error: attribute ‘ghc822’ missing, at (string):1:53
(use ‘--show-trace’ to show detailed location information)
```

What does this error mean and how could I proceed? When I run `$ stack build --show-trace` as suggested, I get the following output, which I do not understand either.

```
$ stack build --show-trace
Invalid option `--show-trace'

Usage: stack build [TARGET] [--dry-run] [--pedantic] [--fast]
                   [--ghc-options OPTIONS] [--flag PACKAGE:[-]FLAG]
                   ([--dependencies-only] | [--only-snapshot] |
                   [--only-dependencies]) ([--file-watch] | [--file-watch-poll])
                   [--exec CMD [ARGS]] [--only-configure] [--trace] [--profile]
                   [--no-strip] [--[no-]library-profiling]
                   [--[no-]executable-profiling] [--[no-]library-stripping]
                   [--[no-]executable-stripping] [--[no-]haddock]
                   [--haddock-arguments HADDOCK_ARGS] [--[no-]open]
                   [--[no-]haddock-deps] [--[no-]haddock-internal]
                   [--[no-]haddock-hyperlink-source] [--[no-]copy-bins]
                   [--[no-]copy-compiler-tool] [--[no-]prefetch]
                   [--[no-]keep-going] [--[no-]force-dirty] [--[no-]test]
                   [--[no-]rerun-tests] [--ta|--test-arguments TEST_ARGS]
                   [--coverage] [--no-run-tests] [--[no-]bench]
                   [--ba|--benchmark-arguments BENCH_ARGS] [--no-run-benchmarks]
                   [--[no-]reconfigure] [--[no-]cabal-verbose]
                   [--[no-]split-objs] [--skip ARG] [--help]
  Build the package(s) in this directory/configuration
```

---

I tried changing my channel to `nixos-17.09` instead of `nixos-unstable` (and running `nix-channel --update`), but still get the same error.

Output of `$ nix-channel --list` is shown below.

```
$ nix-channel --list
stack https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-17.09
nixos https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-17.09
```

---

The output of `$ nix-env -qaPA 'nixos.haskell.compiler'` shows ghc822 to be found.

```
$ nix-env -qaPA 'nixos.haskell.compiler'
warning: name collision in input Nix expressions, skipping ‘/home/matthew/.nix-defexpr/channels_root/nixos’
nixos.haskell.compiler.ghc6102Binary           ghc-6.10.2-binary
nixos.haskell.compiler.ghc704                  ghc-7.0.4
nixos.haskell.compiler.ghc704Binary            ghc-7.0.4-binary
nixos.haskell.compiler.ghc7102                 ghc-7.10.2
nixos.haskell.compiler.integer-simple.ghc7102  ghc-7.10.2
nixos.haskell.compiler.ghc7103                 ghc-7.10.3
nixos.haskell.compiler.integer-simple.ghc7103  ghc-7.10.3
nixos.haskell.compiler.integer-simple.ghc742   ghc-7.4.2
nixos.haskell.compiler.ghc742                  ghc-7.4.2
nixos.haskell.compiler.ghc742Binary            ghc-7.4.2-binary
nixos.haskell.compiler.ghc763                  ghc-7.6.3
nixos.haskell.compiler.ghc783                  ghc-7.8.3
nixos.haskell.compiler.integer-simple.ghc783   ghc-7.8.3
nixos.haskell.compiler.ghc784                  ghc-7.8.4
nixos.haskell.compiler.integer-simple.ghc784   ghc-7.8.4
nixos.haskell.compiler.ghc801                  ghc-8.0.1
nixos.haskell.compiler.integer-simple.ghc801   ghc-8.0.1
nixos.haskell.compiler.ghc802                  ghc-8.0.2
nixos.haskell.compiler.integer-simple.ghc802   ghc-8.0.2
nixos.haskell.compiler.integer-simple.ghc821   ghc-8.2.1
nixos.haskell.compiler.ghc821                  ghc-8.2.1
nixos.haskell.compiler.integer-simple.ghc822   ghc-8.2.2
nixos.haskell.compiler.ghc822                  ghc-8.2.2
nixos.haskell.compiler.integer-simple.ghcHEAD  ghc-8.3.20170808
nixos.haskell.compiler.ghcHEAD                 ghc-8.3.20170808
nixos.haskell.compiler.ghcjs                   ghcjs-0.2.0
nixos.haskell.compiler.ghcjsHEAD               ghcjs-0.2.020170323
nixos.haskell.compiler.jhc                     jhc-0.8.2
nixos.haskell.compiler.uhc                     uhc-1.1.9.4
```

I installed `ghc8.2.2` via `$ nix-env -iA nixos.haskell.compiler.ghc822`, and `$ ghc --version` now returns

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.2.2
```

However, I still get the error `error: attribute ‘ghc822’ missing, at (string):1:54` when attempting to run `$ stack build`.

Also, I attempted to see what `ghc` version my `stack` is using after this install, and this led to the same `attribute ‘ghc822’ missing` error.

```
$ stack ghc -- --version
error: attribute ‘ghc822’ missing, at (string):1:54
(use ‘--show-trace’ to show detailed location information)
```

Comment: Try running `nix-env -qaPA 'nixos.haskell.compiler'` and see if `8.2.2` was found or not. I am using `nixos-unstable` and I have `ghc822`.

Comment: @wizzup the output of that command does show `ghc822` (question edited to show that command's output).

Comment: Then I have no idea. You may try adding `--nix` to stack commands. for example, `stack --nix build`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As palik commented, changing the resolver version -- in my case changing

`resolver: lts-11.3`

to

`resolver: lts-9.1`

in `stack.yaml` is a work-around. I do not know what the deeper issue is but would be interested to know.

---

Update: [this post](https://typeclasses.com/stack-and-nix) provides a thorough explanation with excellent tips on how to use stackage and nix in concert, including how to reach agreement between package versions of the stack resolver and nix channel.

---

How to know which resolver to specify in stack.yaml?

Go to this url, which shows stackage snapshots containing ghc:
https://www.stackage.org/package/ghc/snapshots

This will tell you the resolver corresponding to the ghc version you have. For example, I have ghc 8.10.7,

```
$ ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 8.10.7
```

and doing a find '8.10.7' on that page shows me that corresponds to `LTS Haskell 18.28 (ghc-8.10.7)`. So I would specify `resolver: lts-18.28` in my `stack.yaml`.

(How to find resolvers for a given package was found in an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54307203/how-can-i-find-a-stack-resolver-that-contains-my-package).)

Comment: I had a similar issue, and like you, changing my `resolver` from in my case `nightly-2018-05-21` to `lts-11.15` fixed it as well. Thank you!

Comment: If you have trouble identifying which resolver to set, you can try `stack config set resolver lts`, as described here: https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/faq/#what-version-of-ghc-is-used-when-i-run-something-like-stack-ghci.

Answer (score 7):

It seems like your stack wants to retrieve the `haskell.packages.ghc822` attribute or perhaps `haskell.compiler.ghc822`, which is not present in your version of `<nixpkgs>`.

Please check your channel configuration using `sudo nix-channel --list` (NixOS) or `nix-channel --list`. Releases 17.03 and older do not have this attribute. 17.09 and unstable should be fine. To switch your default `<nixpkgs>` to 17.09, note the name of the channel and run

```
nix-channel --add https://nixos.org/channels/nixos-17.09 <NAME>
```

Also run `nix-channel --update` to make sure you have a recent version. GHC 8.2.2 was added on Oct 31st.

If you don't want to change your channel configuration, I suppose you can set the `NIX_PATH` environment variable

```
NIX_PATH=nixpkgs=https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs-channels/archive/nixos-unstable.tar.gz stack build
```

Comment: My `nix-channel` was `nixos-unstable`. For good measure I changed it to `nixos-17.09` per these instructions (and ran `nix-channel --update`) but still get the same error.

Comment: Searching for `ghc` in the results of `nix-env -qaP '*' --description` I do not see `ghc-8.2.2` (only `ghc-8.0.2`).

Comment: Perhaps the reference to nixpkgs is made by other means, such as the `nix`/`path` variable in `stack.yaml`, or `nix`/`shell-file`? See https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/blob/master/doc/nix_integration.md

Comment: I replaced `resolver: lts-10.2` by `lts-9.1` in `stack.yaml` to work around the issue.

Answer (score 5):

Another option is to use a `shell.nix`. **nixos-18.03** comes with **ghc 8.2.2**, so you can create a `shell.nix` like:

```
with import (builtins.fetchGit {
    url = https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs-channels;
    ref = "nixos-18.03";
    rev = "cb0e20d6db96fe09a501076c7a2c265359982814";
}) {};

haskell.lib.buildStackProject {
    name = "my-project";
    buildInputs = [ ghc <otherlibs-here> ];
}
```

And add the following to your `stack.yaml`:

```
nix:
  shell-file: shell.nix
```

Then `stack build` as usual.

Answer (score 3):

You can provide an old GHC version using a `shell.nix` file place in the root of your project:

```
with import (fetchTarball https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/83b35508c6491103cd16a796758e07417a28698b.tar.gz) {};
let ghc = haskell.compiler.ghc802;
in haskell.lib.buildStackProject {
    inherit ghc;
    name = "myEnv";
    buildInputs = [ pcre ];
}
```

Use a tar url from https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/releases for a version of nixpkgs that contains the GHC version you need.

Then run `nix-shell` in the root of the project. This will put you into a shell in which you can perform `stack build` successfully since it would have access to the correct GHC version.

Answer (score 0):

based on @steve-chávez answer

stack.yaml

```
resolver: lts-13.19
system-ghc: true
install-ghc: false

nix:
  enable: true
  path: [nixpkgs=./nix/nixpkgs/default.nix]
  shell-file: shell.nix
```

nix/nixpkgs/default.nix

```
let
  spec = builtins.fromJSON (builtins.readFile ./revision.json);

  src = import <nix/fetchurl.nix> {
    url = "https://github.com/${spec.owner}/${spec.repo}/archive/${spec.rev}.tar.gz";
    inherit (spec) sha256;
  };
  nixcfg = import <nix/config.nix>;

  nixpkgs = builtins.derivation {
    system = builtins.currentSystem;
    name = "${src.name}-unpacked";
    builder = builtins.storePath nixcfg.shell;
    inherit src;
    args = [
      (builtins.toFile "builder" ''
        $coreutils/mkdir $out
        cd $out
        $gzip -d < $src | $tar -x --strip-components=1
      '')
    ];
    coreutils = builtins.storePath nixcfg.coreutils;
    tar = builtins.storePath nixcfg.tar;
    gzip = builtins.storePath nixcfg.gzip;
  };
in
  import nixpkgs
```

nix/nixpkgs/update.sh

```
#!/usr/bin/env nix-shell
#!nix-shell -i bash -p nix curl jq

SCRIPT_DIR=$(dirname "$(readlink -f "$BASH_SOURCE")")

owner="nixos"
repo="nixpkgs-channels"
rev="nixos-unstable"

full_rev=$(curl --silent https://api.github.com/repos/$owner/$repo/git/refs/heads/$rev | jq -r .object.sha)

echo "full_rev=$full_rev"

expected_sha=$(nix-prefetch-url https://github.com/$owner/$repo/archive/$full_rev.tar.gz)

cat >"$SCRIPT_DIR/revision.json" <<EOL
{
  "owner":  "$owner",
  "repo":   "$repo",
  "rev":    "$full_rev",
  "sha256": "$expected_sha"
}
EOL
```

shell.nix

```
{
  #
  # there are 2 ways of using stack with nix
  # - define custom packages in `stack.yaml` `packages` option (https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/nix_integration/#additions-to-your-stackyaml)
  # - define custom package in `shell.nix` AND `shell-file: ...` in `stack.yaml` (https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/nix_integration/#additions-to-your-stackyaml)
  #
  # we are using second option

  ghc # stack expect this file to define a function of exactly one argument that should be called ghc
}:


let
  # pkgs = import ./nix/nixpkgs/default.nix {}
  pkgs = import <nixpkgs> {};
in

with pkgs;

haskell.lib.buildStackProject {
  inherit ghc;
  name = "myEnv";
  buildInputs = [ cabal-install ];
}
```