# "ghc-cabal: No such file or directory" error while building Haskell Stack example in NixOS

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack, nixos

**A)** I'm trying to create a Haskell project i) with Stack, ii) on NixOS (channels/nixos-18.03). While following the [HelloWorld example](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/GUIDE/#hello-world-example) in the user guide, to build the project, I get the error `ghc-cabal: No such file or directory`.

```
$ stack new helloworld new-template
$ cd helloworld
$ sudo stack build
...
Running /run/current-system/sw/bin/make install in directory /root/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.4.temp/ghc-8.6.4/ exited with ExitFailure 2
...
utils/ghc-cabal/dist-install/build/tmp/ghc-cabal-bindist: line 3: /root/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.4.temp/ghc-8.6.4/utils/ghc-cabal/dist-install/build/tmp/ghc-cabal: No such file or directory
make[1]: *** [ghc.mk:990: install_packages] Error 127
make: *** [Makefile:51: install] Error 2

Error: Error encountered while installing GHC with
         make install
         run in /root/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.4.temp/ghc-8.6.4/

       The following directories may now contain files, but won't be used by stack:
         - /root/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.4.temp/
         - /root/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.4/
```

**B)** Iteratively, I've built up my `/etc/nixos/configuration.nix` file to look like this. And in the resulting system, indeed there's no `ghc-cabal` binary. There's `cabal`, but no `ghc-cabal`.

```
  environment.systemPackages = with pkgs; [
    wget vim emacs
    pkgs.firefoxWrapper pkgs.chromium

    stack
    haskellPackages.ghc
    haskellPackages.cabal-install
    haskellPackages.cabal2nix
    haskellPackages.hdevtools

    tree gnumake which binutils gcc clang coreutils gnutar
    tmux silver-searcher gitAndTools.gitFull
  ];
```

**C)** I've also followed the steps in Stack's [Nix Integration](https://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/nix_integration/) section. But to no avail.

What package installs `ghc-cabal`? Is there a mismatch between `stack` and `haskellPackages.cabal-install`? What am I missing?

**EDIT**

I did a bit of digging around and came across some useful resources.
In particular, [this article](https://osoco.es/thoughts/2018/07/gradle-and-nixos/) points out that my problem could be  caused by an unresolved dynamic library.

Indeed when querying the loaded libraries for that binary, I get the result below.

```
$ ldd ~/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-8.6.4.temp/ghc-8.6.4/utils/ghc-cabal/dist-install/build/tmp/ghc-cabal
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff0ab01000)
    libm.so.6 => /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007fe82c07f000)
    libHSCabal-2.4.0.1-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libHSprocess-1.6.5.0-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libHSpretty-1.1.3.6-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libHSparsec-3.1.13.0-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libHStext-1.2.3.1-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libHSmtl-2.2.2-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libHStransformers-0.5.6.2-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libHSdirectory-1.3.3.0-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libHSunix-2.7.2.2-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libHStime-1.8.0.2-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libHSfilepath-1.4.2.1-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libHSbinary-0.8.6.0-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libHScontainers-0.6.0.1-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libHSbytestring-0.10.8.2-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libHSdeepseq-1.4.4.0-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libHSarray-0.5.3.0-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libHSbase-4.12.0.0-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libHSinteger-gmp-1.0.2.0-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libHSghc-prim-0.5.3-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libHSrts-ghc8.6.4.so => not found
    libffi.so.7 => not found
    librt.so.1 => /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/librt.so.1 (0x00007fe82c06d000)
    libutil.so.1 => /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/libutil.so.1 (0x00007fe82c068000)
    libdl.so.2 => /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe82c063000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007fe82c042000)
    libgmp.so.10 => not found
    libc.so.6 => /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe82be8a000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 => /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe82c219000)
```

I tried resolving the missing libs, by adding `haskellPackages.stdio` and `haskellPackages.stdf` to configuration.nix. But further upstream errors spring from that (ex: I can't add aeson as an `environment.systemPackages` dependency). So I haven't gotten the right mix yet.

```
CallStack (from HasCallStack):
  die', called at libraries/Cabal/Cabal/Distribution/Simple/Configure.hs:950:20 in Cabal-2.4.0.1:Distribution.Simple.Configure
  configureFinalizedPackage, called at libraries/Cabal/Cabal/Distribution/Simple/Configure.hs:460:12 in Cabal-2.4.0.1:Distribution.Simple.Configure
  configure, called at libraries/Cabal/Cabal/Distribution/Simple.hs:596:20 in Cabal-2.4.0.1:Distribution.Simple
  confHook, called at libraries/Cabal/Cabal/Distribution/Simple/UserHooks.hs:67:5 in Cabal-2.4.0.1:Distribution.Simple.UserHooks
  configureAction, called at libraries/Cabal/Cabal/Distribution/Simple.hs:178:19 in Cabal-2.4.0.1:Distribution.Simple
  defaultMainHelper, called at libraries/Cabal/Cabal/Distribution/Simple.hs:115:27 in Cabal-2.4.0.1:Distribution.Simple
  defaultMain, called at Setup.hs:2:8 in main:Main
Setup: Encountered missing dependencies:
aeson ==0.8.*, base ==4.7.*, binary ==0.7.*, text ==1.1.*
```

Comment: Why are you using `sudo` to run `stack build`?

Comment: @JosephSible Same error happens with an without `sudo`. I tried with `sudo` to see if that was the problem.

Comment: Have you tried `stack build --nix`?

Comment: Seems to be mentioned on this github issue: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/4196

Comment: @ChrisStryczynski Running `stack build --nix` gives me `error: attribute 'ghc864' missing, at (string):1:43`. So thanks for pointing our that GH issue. I added to that issue, adding this thread to the pile. As outlined above, I tried manually adding the missing libs, but got more missing dependency errors (which I can't add). So maybe the devs have more insight.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47916591/stack-build-error-attribute-ghc822-missing-at-string153/47922106 could be a similar issue to this too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this with the help of [Kirill Zaborsky](https://github.com/qrilka) in a `commercialhaskell/stack` issues [thread](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/4196). The cause of the error (in `stack new` and `stack build`) was an old Stack version. Specifically, my local user had an older stack (`1.6.5`) than root (`1.9.3`).

Version 1.6.5 uses `Cabal-2.0`, and since then new features were introduced by `Cabal` (ex `base-noprelude`) use leading commas, implemented in [haskell/cabal#4953](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/4953) which came with 2.2. So Stack fails parsing cabal files using the new format features.

Details are in the `commercialhaskell/stack` issues [thread](https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/4196). And upgrading my local user's stack (`nix-env --upgrade stack`) fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

ghc-cabal is an artifact in ghc's build, included in ghc binary distributions:

```
$ ls -l  ~/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.6.3.tar.xz
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user group 182356948 Dec 25 15:11 ghc-tinfo6-8.6.3.tar.xz
$ tar tvf ~/.stack/programs/x86_64-linux/ghc-tinfo6-8.6.3.tar.xz | grep tmp/ghc-cabal
-rwxr-xr-x ghc/ghc      225936 2018-12-08 00:03 ghc-8.6.3/utils/ghc-cabal/dist-install/build/tmp/ghc-cabal
-rwxr-xr-x ghc/ghc         858 2018-12-08 00:03 ghc-8.6.3/utils/ghc-cabal/dist-install/build/tmp/ghc-cabal-bindist
```

Comment: Yes agreed. I guess what I'm wondering is why including `stack` in `environment.systemPackages`, doesn't pull down all needed dependencies, including ghc. I tried explicitly including `ghc`, and get the same error.